# Cannot open Sublime Text 3 - expected a comma or closing bracket in packages\user\preferences.sublime-settings:8:2

Tags: parsing, sublimetext3

I was configuring SublimeText 3, and I think I've done some pretty bad mistake.

When I try to open SublimeText I get this message:

```
Error trying to parse settings: unexpected character, 
expected a comma or closing bracket in 
packages\user\preferences.sublime-settings:8:2
```

I tried to open the documents, run as admin everything.

**Question:**

Any idea about a solution for this?

Comment: Can you paste your setting file?

Comment: Sofia Gonzales - As @overcomer has hinted your best next step is to open your settings file. The file location is in the error message. Use another text editor to open it, Text Edit or Notepad or whatever you've got. Look at the location given in the error message and chances are you will that you are missing a comma or a closing bracket just as the error message suggests. If it isn't obvious to you then edit your question and post your settings file.